# How to keep the state of input checkbox on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

How do I store a cookie for input checkbox current state? Every time when the page reloads, the state is restored to default (unchecked) and I've been buzzing my head with this. I even used a library without any success

https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie `Cookie.set()` and `Cookie.get()` but without success.

I've been also reading about `localStorage` JavaScript API but can't seem to getting working.

jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click( () => {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true, localStorage.getItem('checked')).attr('checked', 'checked');
            localStorage.setItem('checked', 'checked');
            $('img').attr('src', '/full_logo_transparent.png');
            $('link#hueman-main-style-css').attr('href', '/darkstyle.min.css');
            console.log('Dark Mode enabled');
        } else {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
            $('link#hueman-main-style-css').attr('href', '/main.min.css');
        }
    })
});
```

This is suppose to remember the state of the input checkbox and save it upon page reload so that it doesn't have to be toggled every single time (It loads additional `CSS` file)

Am I missing something? Is the order correct?

The site is https://itmagazin.info and on the right you will find `input:checkbox` with the name **"Noćni Režim"** which activates the dark mode, but it doesn't stay that way after you click on any article.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are only assigning a click handler to the input field there - you are not doing anything else _on load_ ...

Comment: You are passing `localStorage.getItem('checked')` as the 3rd argument to the JQuery `.prop()` method, which doesn't take 3 arguments. and there is no need to set the `.attr` and the `.prop`.

Comment: CBroe Ok, so do I need to add `window.onload()` or something like that?
Scott, I know that `.attr` is not necessary I was just testing something and I need the `.prop` otherwise it won't load the addition `CSS` file in the `DOM`.

Comment: _"so do I need to add window.onload() or something like that?"_ - no, because you are using `$(function () {})` already. You just got to actually _do something_ with the stored value in there, and not just set up a handler that will wait for the input to be clicked ...

Comment: CBroe, ok thank you for the info, appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much simpler than you are doing. Just get the last stored value upon page load and set it appropriately based on the state of the checkbox after being clicked.

The following code won't work in the Stack Overflow snippet environment, due to sandboxing, but you can test it **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/s3qaphuv/10/)**.

```js
$(function () {
  // Reset the checkbox to the last state on the last visit
  // The value in localStorage will be the strings "true", "false" or
  // it won't be there at all, in which case "" will be returned.
  // The opposite of "true" (or !"true") is the Boolean false and the
  // opposite of that (!!"true") is the Boolean true.  The opposite of
  // "" (!"") is the Boolean true and the opposite of that (!!"") is the
  // Boolean false
  $('#check').prop("checked", !!localStorage.getItem("darkMode"));

  $('#check').on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'true');
      $('img').attr('src', '/full_logo_transparent.png');
      $('link#hueman-main-style-css').attr('href', '/darkstyle.min.css');
      console.log('Dark Mode enabled');
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('darkMode', 'false');
      $('link#hueman-main-style-css').attr('href', '/main.min.css');
      console.log("No Dark Mode");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="test" id="check"><label for="check">Item</label>
```

Comment: I'll give it try. Thank you.

Comment: Hm.. I believe that this is what I'm looking for, but for some reason the input is now unclickable. I've put your code on the site https://itmagazin.info ("NOĆNI REŽIM" toggler). Oh and the code is in "app.js >ln 39"

Comment: I'm sorry, but you shouldn't expect us to go out and debug live web pages. You can see from the Fiddle that the code does work. If it's not working now that you've integrated it with your site, the problem must be with some other code on your site. I did have one typo in my answer (and on the Fiddle) that I have since corrected, but that wouldn't cause the issue you are describing.

Comment: non existent localStorage key doesn't return empty string. Also `!!'false'` and `!!'true'` both return true. Could convert to boolean with JSON.parse()`